# How to look through arrays?

Tags: c#

I want a way to look through an array with a certain criteria.
For example,

```
str[] balance = { hi.Text, bye.Text, hello.Text, what.Text };
```

How do I look through it with the criteria of "more than 4 characters" so it would look at each one, and skip it if it doesn't meet the criteria. 
So like in this example, it would skip hi and bye, but not hello.

Comment: LINQ could easily do this in one simple line, what is `str`, do you mean `string`?

Comment: What is "LINQ"?

Comment: [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq)

Comment: @paulodiogo Please don't edit the code in questions (and answers), except for typos in comments and output strings, and indentation (unless the language is one that depends on indentations, like Python). You may end up either fixing the problem, or causing further bugs. If you really feel the code needs changing, post a comment to that effect and let the author of the post do the edit. (The two reviewers who accepted your suggested edit were both wrong and don't seem to understand what is an acceptable edit.)

Comment: @robinCTS https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fourOrMore = balance.Where(x => x.Length > 4).ToList();
```

Would do exactly what you need, you would need to add `using System.Linq;` to you class file

Comment: When I use this, I get an error saying "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable" Here's my array, string[] labels = {label5.Text, label13.Text, label6.Text, label14.Text, label7.Text,
label8.Text, label12.Text, label9.Text, label11.Text, label10.Text
};

Comment: Are you sure you have the exact line of code I do? Because from the error usually means you are calling a method without `()`

Comment: Oh it works now, may have just been a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Mark as answer if this helped you! No worries

Comment: Wait last thing, how do I actually use this?

Comment: its a `List<string>` so treat it as one, so for example `fourOrMore[0]` is the first element, I recommend looking into [Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) . Or instead of `.ToList()` call `.ToArray()`

Comment: So I have another problem now, I'm not even sure if this is valid but I put: MessageBox.Show(fourOrMore[0]); and it's giving me an error

Comment: @JustinHomae I would suggest that you read some basic tutorials and learn the basics in regards to coding.. `MessageBox.Show(fourOrMore[0)]` you need to do `.ToString()` at the end 
`MessageBox.Show(fourOrMore[0].ToString());`